# undefined in Isabelle/HOL

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

I was trying to prove this lemma in Isabelle/HOL.

`lemma "(0::nat) ≠ undefined"`

But nitpick finds counterexamples to both this and it's negation

`lemma "(0::nat) = undefined"`

How is this possible? I looked up how undefined is defined and it's an axiom:

`axiomatization undefined :: 'a`

But it's still classical logic, right? So either `"(0::nat) = undefined"` or `"(0::nat) ≠ undefined"` should be true.

Background:

I have a function of type:

`type_synonym myfun = "nat ⇒ nat"`

and I impose constraints on its image and domain in a locale. When I tried to take a specific function and show that it fulfills all conditions in the locale I got problems since some of the conditions only hold for values that are not undefined.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By axiomatisation, each type has one designated value that is `undefined`. This is not some separate value that lives outside the normal range of that type, i.e. `undefined :: nat` is a natural number, but you do not know *which* natural number it is, and in fact you will not be able to prove any non-trivial property about `undefined`. A trivial property in this context is one that holds for *all* values of the type.

Therefore, the statement `undefined ≠ (0 :: nat)` is not provable in Isabelle/HOL, and neither is its negation (bugs and inconsistencies aside).

For `undefined :: bool` in particular, we know that `undefined = True ∨ undefined = False`, but again, you will not be able to prove `undefined = True` or `undefined = False`.

For the unit type (the one-element type consisting only of the value `() :: unit`), however, you *can* prove `undefined = ()`, since this is a trivial property.

As for your original problem, it sounds as if you have to change the way you model undefinedness in your application. Since you did not give any details about what you are doing, it is not really possible to give any specific advice about what to do. But trying to prove anything about `undefined` is not going to work.

Comment: Thank you so much this helped me a lot. I resorted to map values to 0 instead of undefined now.

Sorry I meant that either (0::nat) = undefined or (0::nat) ≠ undefined should hold. I edited the question above.

Comment: Yes, picking a suitable dummy value (like 0) instead of `undefined` can often make your life easier. I will update my answer to remove the part referring to that typo.

Comment: You can prove `lemma "undefined = (0::nat) ∨ undefined ≠ (0::nat)"
  by blast` without a problem.